# How do you configure Destructurama.Attributes .Destructure.UsingAttribues() in JSON from appsettings?

Tags: serilog

We use appsettings to configure Serilog via JSON, a fairly standard enterprise practice.
But I'm having trouble enabling the UsingAttributes. How does one enable **.Destructure.UsingAttributes** via JSON config?

I started with a pure Serliog approach, but they indicate that [Serilog.Extras.Attributed](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Extras.Attributed) is deprecated in favor of using [Destructurama.Attributed](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Destructurama.Attributed/). And in looking at the [Destructurama.Attributed github example](https://github.com/destructurama/attributed), I don't understand how to convert that into a JSON configuration. Their example:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration().Destructure.UsingAttributes()
```

The [Serilog documentation](https://github.com/tsimbalar/serilog-settings-comparison/blob/master/docs/README.md#custom-destructuring) for the "Destructure" option is straightforward:

```
"Destructure": [
  {
    "Name": "With",
    "Args": { "policy": "Sample.CustomPolicy, Sample" }
  },
 ],
```

However, I don't know what I would use for the `"Sample.CustomPolicy, Sample"` to get Destructurama to be enabled.

```
"Destructure": [
  {
    "Name": "With",
    "Args": { "UsingAttributes": WHAT_GOES_HERE}
  },
 ],
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4):

I just encountered the same problem and after a few experiments I figured how to have it working using Destructurama.Attributed version 2.0.0 :

1. You must specify the following using in JSON configuration to make Serilog able to see the library :

> ```
> "Serilog":
> {
>   "Using":
>   [
>     "Destructurama.Attributed"
>   ],
>    ....
> }
> ```

2. Inside Serilog configuration, you have to specify this to Destructure to enable the attributes :

> ```
> "Destructure":
> [
>   {
>       "Name": "UsingAttributes"
>   },
>   ....
> ]
> ```

Comment: Make sure the above entries are placed first in each array.